# How to handle (R) symbol during XML XSLT transformation

Tags: java, xml, xslt, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an UTF-8 XML (passed as a string) which contains the following line:

`<LongName>SomeName®</LongName>`.

And it should be transformed into another UTF-8 XML after XSLT transformation. The problem is only with ® symbol, it's transformed into two symbols: Â®

Here's the code:

```
public String transform (String inputXML) throws TransformerException {
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream transformationFile = getClass().getResourceAsStream(TRANSFORMER_PATH);
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(transformationFile));
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputXML.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    Source input = new StreamSource(is);

    transformer.transform(input, new StreamResult(os));
    return os.toString();
}
```

So the question is - how to correctly transform ® to ® from UTF-8 to UTF-8 XML?

Comment: It looks like you aren't reading the source as UTF8.

Comment: What should I do to fix it?

Comment: You are reading the bytes of the UTF-8 encoding of the codepoint sequence stored in inputXML. Don't do that: Create a stream from the String and throw this at the transform.

Comment: How to create a stream without messing with bytes? `IOUtils.toInputStream(inputXML)` is doing exactly the same for example.

Comment: You have your input in a String, so you should use a StreamSource(Reader reader) with a StringReader from that inputXML.

Comment: have tried it - still same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is the last line:

```
return os.toString();
```

Since `os` is a `ByteArrayOutputStream` it has to convert the byte array to a `String` and it will use the current platform default encoding instead of `UTF-8`. You may use [`return os.toString("UTF-8");`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toString%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputXML.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  Source input = new StreamSource(is);
```

try

```
 Source input = new StreamSource(StringReader(inputXML));
```

Comment: unfortunately same issue